# 'getInstance(io.realm.RealmConfiguration)' in 'io.realm.Realm' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context)' error

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm adding a new database using realm and when i added
  Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
i get this error

```
 'getInstance(io.realm.RealmConfiguration)' in 'io.realm.Realm' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context)'
```

i cant slove it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mobile);
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    final EditText mobType =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText mobModel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText mobStorage =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText mobRam =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    Button addMob = findViewById(R.id.addbutton2);
    addMob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MobileJ mobilej = new MobileJ();
            mobilej.setMobtype(mobType.getText().toString());
            mobilej.setMobmodel(mobModel.getText().toString());
            mobilej.setMobRAM(mobRam.getText().length());
            mobilej.setMobstorge(mobStorage.getText().length());

            Realm realmm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(getApplicationContext());
            realmm.beginTransaction();
            realmm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mobilej);
            realmm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#opening-realms

Comment: Stop following tutorials that were written for 0.82.2

Answer (score 1):

You can get Realm instance in 2 ways:

> 1. Realm.getDefaultInstance();

You don't need to pass any argument to this method. In your code you did that.

> 2. Realm.getInstance(config);

This method requires RealmConfig and not Context.